# Looping through an array to remove a touched object (iPhone/Cocos2d)

Tags: iphone, arrays, cocos2d-iphone, ccsprite

I am using cocos2d to build a game. I have an array of CCSprites and I want to be able to touch them and delete the one that was touched.

Right now I have this...

```
-(void) spawn {
   mySprite = [CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"image.png"];
   mySprite.position = ccp(positionX,positionY);
   [myArray addObject:mySprite];
   [self addChild:mySprite];
}
- (void) ccTouchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
   UITouch* touch = [touches anyObject];
   CGPoint location = [touch locationInView: [touch view]]; 

    NSUInteger i, count = [myArray count];
    for (i = 0; i < count; i++) {
    mySprite = (CCSprite *)[myArray objectAtIndex:i];
    if (CGRectContainsPoint([mySprite boundingBox], location)) {

       [self removeChild:mySprite cleanup:YES]; 

    }
}
```

I have never done this before. Does anyone have a solution?

Thanks,
Michael

Comment: What is not working?  Are you just trying to delete an object from an array?  If so, and there's only one to delete, just break when you find it, and if (sprite) [myArray removeObject:sprite];

Comment: well, spawn is on a timer so there should be multiple objects int he array. Everything inside of if(CGRectContainsPoint) does not get called. I want to delete the sprite from the scene.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
- (void) ccTouchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    UITouch* touch = [touches anyObject];
    CGPoint location = [touch locationInView: [touch view]]; 
    NSMutableArray *spritesToDelete = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    for(CCSprite* mySprite in myArray) {
        if (CGRectContainsPoint([mySprite boundingBox], location))
            [spritesToDelete addObject:mySprite];

    for(CCSprite* deadSprite in spritesToDelete) {
        [self removeChild:deadSprite cleanup:YES];
        [myArray removeObject:deadSprite];
    }
}
```

This code uses a for-each to create an array of the objects that meet your condition, and then removes them.

Comment: The above code does not seem to work. I made sure that I initialized my array and that I was adding objects to it. I also made sure I am touchesEnabled

Comment: Haha it was a stupid mistake, I mismatched the names of the arrays. Fixed now.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. I am still learning to make games and have almost no experience with cocos2d. I am going to try to build my game using just the standard iphone libraries. I got it to work without cocos2d!

Comment: You can omit the spritesToDelete array if you iterate over myArray backwards (not using fast enumeration).

Comment: Also, the code above has a bug, it does not remove the dead sprites from the myArray array.